# Assign new value to variable fails

Tags: shell

why this do not work:

```
if [ $_TYPE == 1 ] || [ $_TYPE == 2 ]; then
                $_TYPE=$(echo "Outbound");
fi

or

if [ $_TYPE == 1 ] || [ $_TYPE == 2 ]; then
                $_TYPE=echo "Outbound";
fi

or

if [ $_TYPE == 1 ] || [ $_TYPE == 2 ]; then
                $_TYPE="Outbound";
fi
```

I'm receiving this error:  line 251: 2=Outbound: command not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In POSIX shells such as Bash, `$` is not part of the variable-name, it's just the notation for *expanding* the variable (to obtain its value); so, for example, `echo "$_TYPE"` prints the value of the variable `_TYPE`. You don't use the `$` when you're assigning to the variable. So you just need:

```
if [[ "$_TYPE" = 1 || "$_TYPE" = 2 ]] ; then
    _TYPE=Outbound
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

$ is used to access the value, but if you have to assign a value, the syntax is :

```
_TYPE="newValue"
```